# Assigning a timestamp to a taken screenshot

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB, and I'm having some trouble. I created a button to screenshot the window when pressed, however I want each screenshot to have its own timestamp, so they don't keep overwriting each other. This is the code I have now:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SC As New ScreenShot.ScreenCapture

    Dim MyWindow As Image = SC.CaptureWindow(Me.Handle)

    SC.CaptureWindowToFile(Me.Handle, "c:\temp\image.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub
```

I'm using this custom class:
http://pastebin.com/9at7uESY

How would I have to edit either the class or the code to enable me to timestamp each screenshot taken? Thanks!

Comment: This is such a simple question that I'm thinking I'm missing something. Wouldn't the obvious solution be to change from using a hard-coded file name (`C:\temp\image.jpg`) to using a file name based on the current time instead?

Comment: Are you wanting to add a time stamp to your class, or to the meta data on the image file (or both?)  The current time can be obtained from DateTime.Now (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)

Comment: My first thought was trying to change the hard-coded file name, but that would require editing the class wouldn't it? Exactly what should I edit in it then? Also aring I want to timestamp the name that the picture is saved as, not in the metadata.

Comment: @user2758105 There should be no need to change anything in the class when you change the filename. Could explain why you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the filename (or any string) to contain a date and time use
`"c:\temp\image_" & now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".jpg"`

[Reference on MSDN about the format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Edit: There should be no need to change the class, Just changing the line in your code where you declared the filename.

```
SC.CaptureWindowToFile(Me.Handle, "c:\temp\image.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

To

```
SC.CaptureWindowToFile(Me.Handle, "c:\temp\image_" & now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```